# MessageBodyWriter not found for media type={application/xml, q=1000} - Jersey + Jaxb

Tags: rest, jaxb, jersey, jax-rs

I am writing a RESTful web service with Jersey. I want to return a custom object in XML form to consumer. The error I am getting is:

> MessageBodyWriter not found for media type={application/xml, q=1000}, type=class com.test.ws.Employee, genericType=class com.test.ws.Employee.

Below is the code:

**web.xml**

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd"
id="WebApp_ID" version="3.0">
<display-name>com.vogella.jersey.first</display-name>
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>Jersey REST Service</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer</servlet-class>
    <!-- Register resources and providers under com.vogella.jersey.first package. -->
    <init-param>
        <param-name>jersey.config.server.provider.packages</param-name>
        <param-value>com.test.ws</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>Jersey REST Service</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/rest/*</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
</web-app>
```

**Service Class**

```
package com.test.ws;

@Path("/hello")
public class Hello {

    @GET 
    @Path("/sayHello")
    @Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_XML)
    public Employee sayHello() {
        Employee employee = new Employee();
        employee.setEmpId(1);
        employee.setFirstName("Aniket");
        employee.setLastName("Khadke");
        return employee;
    }
}
```

**Employee.java**

```
package com.test.ws;

import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlElement;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlRootElement;

@XmlRootElement(name = "employee")
public class Employee {

    public String firstName;

    public String lastName;
    public int empId;

    public Employee(String firstName, String lastName, int empId) {
        super();
        this.firstName = firstName;
        this.lastName = lastName;
        this.empId = empId;
    }

    public Employee() {
        super();
    }

    @XmlElement
    public String getFirstName() {
        return firstName;
    }

    public void setFirstName(String firstName) {
        this.firstName = firstName;
    }

    @XmlElement
    public String getLastName() {
        return lastName;
    }

    public void setLastName(String lastName) {
        this.lastName = lastName;
    }

    @XmlElement
    public int getEmpId() {
        return empId;
    }

    public void setEmpId(int empId) {
        this.empId = empId;
    }

}
```

And here is the list of libraries added:

[image: Jars]

Can anyone help me?

Comment: add implements Serializable to Employee class

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I was able to resolve the issue myself. This was because of having conflicting jars included in build path. Here is the snap for jar files.

[image]

Comment: Personally I think completely switching from Jersey 2.x to Jersey 1.x is _not_ a solution to this particular problem.

Comment: Agree. But I had no such specific requirement to use Jersey 2.x. So it works for me.

Comment: This doesn't actually solve the original problem and also doesn't sell out how this step of downgrading jersey solves the problem.

Comment: WHICH conflicting jar ?

Answer (score 2):

I believe your error is in the web.xml. Try changing your  part to this in your web.xml.

```
<servlet>
       <servlet-name>Jersey REST Service</servlet-name>
       <servlet-class>com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer</servlet-class>
       <!-- Register resources and providers under com.vogella.jersey.first package. -->
       <init-param>
           <param-name>com.sun.jersey.config.property.packages</param-name>
        <param-value>com.test.ws</param-value>
       </init-param>
       <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>
```

Answer (score 1):

One way to solve your issue is to create a custom `javax.ws.rs.core.Application` or `org.glassfish.jersey.server.ResourceConfig`. It seems that your server does not detect your providers for the serialization. By implementing your own `Application`, you will be able to specify which provider you want to use. for your example, what you could have done is :

#### MyApplication.java

```
package com.test.ws;

public class MyApplication extends ResourceConfig {
    public MyApplication() {
        //register your resources
        packages("com.test.ws");
        //if you're using Jackson as your XMLProvider for example
        register(JacksonJaxbXMLProvider.class);
    }
}
```

And add the application in your deployment file :

#### web.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd"
         id="WebApp_ID" version="3.0">
    <display-name>com.vogella.jersey.first</display-name>
    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>Jersey REST Service</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer</servlet-class>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>javax.ws.rs.Application</param-name>
            <param-value>com.test.ws.MyApplication</param-value>
        </init-param>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>Jersey REST Service</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/rest/*</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
</web-app>
```

Answer (score 0):

Employee class should implements Serializable interface

Answer (score -1):

I manage a legacy project wich I needed to add a REST web service. This not have Maven.

For jersey 2.25, the last compiled with Java SDK 1.7, I solved adding jar

**jersey-media-jaxb-2.25.jar**

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. You can [search for similar questions](https://stackoverflow.com/search), or refer to the related and linked questions on the right-hand side of the page to find an answer. If you have a related but different question, [ask a new question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask), and include a link to this one to help provide context. See: [Ask questions, get answers, no distractions](https://stackoverflow.com/tour)

Comment: It is possible, but thanks to this post I resolved my problem. I not found another. Another day I will do better. Greetings!